# How do I track down the cause of a JVM crash?

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, java-8, jna

I am using jdk1.8.0_72(32 bit) ,tomcat server 8 and eclipse luna 32 bit to load my native library mylib.dll(shared library).

After i run my server, i got a runtime error in console and the eclipse server stopped. Is it because of my jre version is not match with my library file? Should i downgrade my jre version?

Any advice will be welcome.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00459386, pid=6604, tid=6460
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_72-b15) (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.72-b15 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [mylib.dll+0x59386]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\eclipse\eclipse\hs_err_pid6604.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: What is `mylib.dll`? Do you have native code in a library?  That's where the error occurred.

Comment: It is likely because there is an error in `mylib.dll` at offset `0x59386`, not because of anything the JDK or Tomcat did.

Comment: @JimGarrison actually , the dll is not created by me. It is just my supplier sdk. I just want to make sure that the error is not from my side , so that i can report to them. thanks

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: Access violation at `mylib.dll+0x59386`. Did you examine the error log `D:\eclipse\eclipse\hs_err_pid6604.log`?  Your supplier is probably going to want that.

Comment: okie sure, i will see that. thanks